# What's “hanging punctuation” in French?

Tags: anglais, terminologie

[Hanging punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation) is “a way of typesetting punctuation marks and bullet points, most commonly quotation marks and hyphens, so that they do not disrupt the ‘flow’ of a body of text or ‘break’ the margin of alignment.” (Wikipedia says it better than me  ;)  )

I cannot find any good translation for this concept in French. Anyone with formal typography education around here?  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/page/about.php?source=auto) when you want to translate technical phrases. It's a database of bilingual texts in various language pairs, including French and English.

There is one hit for [hanging punctuation](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=%22hanging+punctuation%22): “***ponctuation hors justification***”, found in a [Quark, Inc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark,_Inc.) [brochure](http://www.quark.com/pdfs/archives/brochure_fr.pdf). I don't have an official reference to offer, but several manufacturers of typographical software (Quark, Adobe) have used the term, as have [books about CSS](http://books.google.com/books?id=_wVgIfJ2ovUC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=%22ponctuation+hors+justification%22+-adobe+-quark+-quarkxpress&source=bl&ots=Lzk-dzXy_J&sig=ysXsA7Hyxi0zsZWoxua7ImJg1ko&hl=en&ei=VGSXTqiyJ83FtAbQ58CbBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAA), so I would guess that it is indeed the standard translation.

The phrase “*[ponctuation hors justification](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ponctuation+hors+justification%22)*” gets a decent number of hits on Google, unlike “*[ponctuation dans la marge](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ponctuation+dans+la+marge%22)*” (which has a single relevant hit), “*[ponctuation pendante](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ponctuation+pendante%22)*” (which isn't much better, in spite of its obviousness as a literal translation), or “*[ponctuation suspendue](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ponctuation+suspendue%22)*” (most of the hits are unrelated).

The question was asked in passing on the [typographie mailing list](https://listes.irisa.fr/wws/arc/typographie/1997-05/msg00102.html), with no conclusive answer.

Comment: asked in passing = demandé au passage ? C'est du vrai english ça ?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez : définition de *in passing* dans l'OED :  *by the way; in the course of some procedure*. Sur internet on trouve la définiton de *in passing* (entre autres ) : http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+passing ; http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/INPASSING ; etc. Donc l'utilisation faite ici par Gilles semble tout à fait convenir à ce qu'il voulait dire.

Comment: Ben j'aurais appris quelque chose. @Laure merci d'avoir fait le boulot à ma place :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's a good tool to know, and a great answer  :)

Answer (score 3):

Une [discussion](https://listes.irisa.fr/wws/arc/typographie/2000-12/msg00095.html) sur la liste typo a utilisé *ponctuation dans la marge*, *ponctuation pendante* et même « hanging punctuation ». J'ai donc l'impression qu'il n'y a pas (au moins qu'il n'y avait pas à l'époque) de traduction consacrée.  La « justification optique » aussi présente dans cette discussion est plus large, la ponctuation pendante est un moyen d'y arriver.

Comment: L'absence de consensus me semblait effectivement prégnante. Merci pour cette référence !